# ActiveRecord after_commit not triggering anymore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, heroku, rails-activerecord

I have a bunch of calls in my User model that are meant to be triggered after a user is created (successfully written to the db) that used to work.  Now I've noticed that they don't seem to be triggered anymore.

```
before_create :generate_access_token
after_commit  :logging, on: :create
after_commit  :send_welcome_email, :create_settings, on: :create
```

I just added the logging method that simply outputs a message if the method is triggered, but it's not showing up in the logs.

```
def logging
  puts "xoxoxo logging user #{self.id} xoxoxo"
end
```

I'm using Ruby 2.1.2 and Rails 3.2.21 on Heroku.

How can I get them to work again?

Here's the output of `User._commit_callbacks`

```
[#<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fce8a691738 @klass=User(id: integer, gender: string, name: string, email: string, fb_id: integer, fb_token: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, interested_in: text, last_login: datetime, access_token: string, access_token_expires: datetime, last_refreshed_friends_at: datetime, dob: date, fofs_available: boolean, updating_graph: boolean, last_daily_picks_seen_at: datetime, limitless_daily_picks: boolean, dps_limit: integer), @kind=:after, @chain=[#<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fce8a691738 ...>], @per_key={:if=>[], :unless=>[]}, @options={:on=>:create, :if=>["transaction_include_action?(:create)"], :unless=>[]}, @raw_filter=:logging, @filter=:logging, @compiled_options="true && (transaction_include_action?(:create))", @callback_id=362>, #<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fce8a697ea8 @klass=User(id: integer, gender: string, name: string, email: string, fb_id: integer, fb_token: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, interested_in: text, last_login: datetime, access_token: string, access_token_expires: datetime, last_refreshed_friends_at: datetime, dob: date, fofs_available: boolean, updating_graph: boolean, last_daily_picks_seen_at: datetime, limitless_daily_picks: boolean, dps_limit: integer), @kind=:after, @chain=[#<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fce8a691738 @klass=User(id: integer, gender: string, name: string, email: string, fb_id: integer, fb_token: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, interested_in: text, last_login: datetime, access_token: string, access_token_expires: datetime, last_refreshed_friends_at: datetime, dob: date, fofs_available: boolean, updating_graph: boolean, last_daily_picks_seen_at: datetime, limitless_daily_picks: boolean, dps_limit: integer), @kind=:after, @chain=[#<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fce8a691738 ...>], @per_key={:if=>[], :unless=>[]}, @options={:on=>:create, :if=>["transaction_include_action?(:create)"], :unless=>[]}, @raw_filter=:logging, @filter=:logging, @compiled_options="true && (transaction_include_action?(:create))", @callback_id=362>, #<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fce8a697ea8 ...>, #<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fce8a696f58 @klass=User(id: integer, gender: string, name: string, email: string, fb_id: integer, fb_token: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, interested_in: text, last_login: datetime, access_token: string, access_token_expires: datetime, last_refreshed_friends_at: datetime, dob: date, fofs_available: boolean, updating_graph: boolean, last_daily_picks_seen_at: datetime, limitless_daily_picks: boolean, dps_limit: integer), @kind=:after, @chain=[...], @per_key={:if=>[], :unless=>[]}, @options={:on=>:create, :if=>["transaction_include_action?(:create)"], :unless=>[]}, @raw_filter=:create_settings, @filter=:create_settings, @compiled_options="true && (transaction_include_action?(:create))", @callback_id=370>], @per_key={:if=>[], :unless=>[]}, @options={:on=>:create, :if=>["transaction_include_action?(:create)"], :unless=>[]}, @raw_filter=:send_welcome_email, @filter=:send_welcome_email, @compiled_options="true && (transaction_include_action?(:create))", @callback_id=366>, #<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fce8a696f58 @klass=User(id: integer, gender: string, name: string, email: string, fb_id: integer, fb_token: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, interested_in: text, last_login: datetime, access_token: string, access_token_expires: datetime, last_refreshed_friends_at: datetime, dob: date, fofs_available: boolean, updating_graph: boolean, last_daily_picks_seen_at: datetime, limitless_daily_picks: boolean, dps_limit: integer), @kind=:after, @chain=[#<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fce8a691738 @klass=User(id: integer, gender: string, name: string, email: string, fb_id: integer, fb_token: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, interested_in: text, last_login: datetime, access_token: string, access_token_expires: datetime, last_refreshed_friends_at: datetime, dob: date, fofs_available: boolean, updating_graph: boolean, last_daily_picks_seen_at: datetime, limitless_daily_picks: boolean, dps_limit: integer), @kind=:after, @chain=[#<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fce8a691738 ...>], @per_key={:if=>[], :unless=>[]}, @options={:on=>:create, :if=>["transaction_include_action?(:create)"], :unless=>[]}, @raw_filter=:logging, @filter=:logging, @compiled_options="true && (transaction_include_action?(:create))", @callback_id=362>, #<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fce8a697ea8 @klass=User(id: integer, gender: string, name: string, email: string, fb_id: integer, fb_token: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, interested_in: text, last_login: datetime, access_token: string, access_token_expires: datetime, last_refreshed_friends_at: datetime, dob: date, fofs_available: boolean, updating_graph: boolean, last_daily_picks_seen_at: datetime, limitless_daily_picks: boolean, dps_limit: integer), @kind=:after, @chain=[...], @per_key={:if=>[], :unless=>[]}, @options={:on=>:create, :if=>["transaction_include_action?(:create)"], :unless=>[]}, @raw_filter=:send_welcome_email, @filter=:send_welcome_email, @compiled_options="true && (transaction_include_action?(:create))", @callback_id=366>, #<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fce8a696f58 ...>], @per_key={:if=>[], :unless=>[]}, @options={:on=>:create, :if=>["transaction_include_action?(:create)"], :unless=>[]}, @raw_filter=:create_settings, @filter=:create_settings, @compiled_options="true && (transaction_include_action?(:create))", @callback_id=370>, #<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fce8a6957e8 @klass=User(id: integer, gender: string, name: string, email: string, fb_id: integer, fb_token: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, interested_in: text, last_login: datetime, access_token: string, access_token_expires: datetime, last_refreshed_friends_at: datetime, dob: date, fofs_available: boolean, updating_graph: boolean, last_daily_picks_seen_at: datetime, limitless_daily_picks: boolean, dps_limit: integer), @kind=:after, @chain=[#<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fce8a691738 @klass=User(id: integer, gender: string, name: string, email: string, fb_id: integer, fb_token: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, interested_in: text, last_login: datetime, access_token: string, access_token_expires: datetime, last_refreshed_friends_at: datetime, dob: date, fofs_available: boolean, updating_graph: boolean, last_daily_picks_seen_at: datetime, limitless_daily_picks: boolean, dps_limit: integer), @kind=:after, @chain=[#<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fce8a691738 ...>], @per_key={:if=>[], :unless=>[]}, @options={:on=>:create, :if=>["transaction_include_action?(:create)"], :unless=>[]}, @raw_filter=:logging, @filter=:logging, @compiled_options="true && (transaction_include_action?(:create))", @callback_id=362>, #<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fce8a697ea8 @klass=User(id: integer, gender: string, name: string, email: string, fb_id: integer, fb_token: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, interested_in: text, last_login: datetime, access_token: string, access_token_expires: datetime, last_refreshed_friends_at: datetime, dob: date, fofs_available: boolean, updating_graph: boolean, last_daily_picks_seen_at: datetime, limitless_daily_picks: boolean, dps_limit: integer), @kind=:after, @chain=[#<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fce8a691738 @klass=User(id: integer, gender: string, name: string, email: string, fb_id: integer, fb_token: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, interested_in: text, last_login: datetime, access_token: string, access_token_expires: datetime, last_refreshed_friends_at: datetime, dob: date, fofs_available: boolean, updating_graph: boolean, last_daily_picks_seen_at: datetime, limitless_daily_picks: boolean, dps_limit: integer), @kind=:after, @chain=[#<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fce8a691738 ...>], @per_key={:if=>[], :unless=>[]}, @options={:on=>:create, :if=>["transaction_include_action?(:create)"], :unless=>[]}, @raw_filter=:logging, @filter=:logging, @compiled_options="true && (transaction_include_action?(:create))", @callback_id=362>, #<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fce8a697ea8 ...>, #<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fce8a696f58 @klass=User(id: integer, gender: string, name: string, email: string, fb_id: integer, fb_token: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, interested_in: text, last_login: datetime, access_token: string, access_token_expires: datetime, last_refreshed_friends_at: datetime, dob: date, fofs_available: boolean, updating_graph: boolean, last_daily_picks_seen_at: datetime, limitless_daily_picks: boolean, dps_limit: integer), @kind=:after, @chain=[...], @per_key={:if=>[], :unless=>[]}, @options={:on=>:create, :if=>["transaction_include_action?(:create)"], :unless=>[]}, @raw_filter=:create_settings, @filter=:create_settings, @compiled_options="true && (transaction_include_action?(:create))", @callback_id=370>], @per_key={:if=>[], :unless=>[]}, @options={:on=>:create, :if=>["transaction_include_action?(:create)"], :unless=>[]}, @raw_filter=:send_welcome_email, @filter=:send_welcome_email, @compiled_options="true && (transaction_include_action?(:create))", @callback_id=366>, #<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fce8a696f58 @klass=User(id: integer, gender: string, name: string, email: string, fb_id: integer, fb_token: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, interested_in: text, last_login: datetime, access_token: string, access_token_expires: datetime, last_refreshed_friends_at: datetime, dob: date, fofs_available: boolean, updating_graph: boolean, last_daily_picks_seen_at: datetime, limitless_daily_picks: boolean, dps_limit: integer), @kind=:after, @chain=[#<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fce8a691738 @klass=User(id: integer, gender: string, name: string, email: string, fb_id: integer, fb_token: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, interested_in: text, last_login: datetime, access_token: string, access_token_expires: datetime, last_refreshed_friends_at: datetime, dob: date, fofs_available: boolean, updating_graph: boolean, last_daily_picks_seen_at: datetime, limitless_daily_picks: boolean, dps_limit: integer), @kind=:after, @chain=[#<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fce8a691738 ...>], @per_key={:if=>[], :unless=>[]}, @options={:on=>:create, :if=>["transaction_include_action?(:create)"], :unless=>[]}, @raw_filter=:logging, @filter=:logging, @compiled_options="true && (transaction_include_action?(:create))", @callback_id=362>, #<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fce8a697ea8 @klass=User(id: integer, gender: string, name: string, email: string, fb_id: integer, fb_token: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, interested_in: text, last_login: datetime, access_token: string, access_token_expires: datetime, last_refreshed_friends_at: datetime, dob: date, fofs_available: boolean, updating_graph: boolean, last_daily_picks_seen_at: datetime, limitless_daily_picks: boolean, dps_limit: integer), @kind=:after, @chain=[...], @per_key={:if=>[], :unless=>[]}, @options={:on=>:create, :if=>["transaction_include_action?(:create)"], :unless=>[]}, @raw_filter=:send_welcome_email, @filter=:send_welcome_email, @compiled_options="true && (transaction_include_action?(:create))", @callback_id=366>, #<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fce8a696f58 ...>], @per_key={:if=>[], :unless=>[]}, @options={:on=>:create, :if=>["transaction_include_action?(:create)"], :unless=>[]}, @raw_filter=:create_settings, @filter=:create_settings, @compiled_options="true && (transaction_include_action?(:create))", @callback_id=370>, #<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fce8a69bf80 @klass=User(id: integer, gender: string, name: string, email: string, fb_id: integer, fb_token: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, interested_in: text, last_login: datetime, access_token: string, access_token_expires: datetime, last_refreshed_friends_at: datetime, dob: date, fofs_available: boolean, updating_graph: boolean, last_daily_picks_seen_at: datetime, limitless_daily_picks: boolean, dps_limit: integer), @kind=:after, @chain=[#<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fce8a691738 @klass=User(id: integer, gender: string, name: string, email: string, fb_id: integer, fb_token: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, interested_in: text, last_login: datetime, access_token: string, access_token_expires: datetime, last_refreshed_friends_at: datetime, dob: date, fofs_available: boolean, updating_graph: boolean, last_daily_picks_seen_at: datetime, limitless_daily_picks: boolean, dps_limit: integer), @kind=:after, @chain=[#<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fce8a691738 ...>], @per_key={:if=>[], :unless=>[]}, @options={:on=>:create, :if=>["transaction_include_action?(:create)"], :unless=>[]}, @raw_filter=:logging, @filter=:logging, @compiled_options="true && (transaction_include_action?(:create))", @callback_id=362>, #<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fce8a697ea8 @klass=User(id: integer, gender: string, name: string, email: string, fb_id: integer, fb_token: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, interested_in: text, last_login: datetime, access_token: string, access_token_expires: datetime, last_refreshed_friends_at: datetime, dob: date, fofs_available: boolean, updating_graph: boolean, last_daily_picks_seen_at: datetime, limitless_daily_picks: boolean, dps_limit: integer), @kind=:after, @chain=[#<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fce8a691738 @klass=User(id: integer, gender: string, name: string, email: string, fb_id: integer, fb_token: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, interested_in: text, last_login: datetime, access_token: string, access_token_expires: datetime, last_refreshed_friends_at: datetime, dob: date, fofs_available: boolean, updating_graph: boolean, last_daily_picks_seen_at: datetime, limitless_daily_picks: boolean, dps_limit: integer), @kind=:after, @chain=[#<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fce8a691738 ...>], @per_key={:if=>[], :unless=>[]}, @options={:on=>:create, :if=>["transaction_include_action?(:create)"], :unless=>[]}, @raw_filter=:logging, @filter=:logging, @compiled_options="true && (transaction_include_action?(:create))", @callback_id=362>, #<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fce8a697ea8 ...>, #<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fce8a696f58 @klass=User(id: integer, gender: string, name: string, email: string, fb_id: integer, fb_token: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, interested_in: text, last_login: datetime, access_token: string, access_token_expires: datetime, last_refreshed_friends_at: datetime, dob: date, fofs_available: boolean, updating_graph: boolean, last_daily_picks_seen_at: datetime, limitless_daily_picks: boolean, dps_limit: integer), @kind=:after, @chain=[...], @per_key={:if=>[], :unless=>[]}, @options={:on=>:create, :if=>["transaction_include_action?(:create)"], :unless=>[]}, @raw_filter=:create_settings, @filter=:create_settings, @compiled_options="true && (transaction_include_action?(:create))", @callback_id=370>], @per_key={:if=>[], :unless=>[]}, @options={:on=>:create, :if=>["transaction_include_action?(:create)"], :unless=>[]}, @raw_filter=:send_welcome_email, @filter=:send_welcome_email, @compiled_options="true && (transaction_include_action?(:create))", @callback_id=366>, #<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fce8a696f58 @klass=User(id: integer, gender: string, name: string, email: string, fb_id: integer, fb_token: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, interested_in: text, last_login: datetime, access_token: string, access_token_expires: datetime, last_refreshed_friends_at: datetime, dob: date, fofs_available: boolean, updating_graph: boolean, last_daily_picks_seen_at: datetime, limitless_daily_picks: boolean, dps_limit: integer), @kind=:after, @chain=[#<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fce8a691738 @klass=User(id: integer, gender: string, name: string, email: string, fb_id: integer, fb_token: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, interested_in: text, last_login: datetime, access_token: string, access_token_expires: datetime, last_refreshed_friends_at: datetime, dob: date, fofs_available: boolean, updating_graph: boolean, last_daily_picks_seen_at: datetime, limitless_daily_picks: boolean, dps_limit: integer), @kind=:after, @chain=[#<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fce8a691738 ...>], @per_key={:if=>[], :unless=>[]}, @options={:on=>:create, :if=>["transaction_include_action?(:create)"], :unless=>[]}, @raw_filter=:logging, @filter=:logging, @compiled_options="true && (transaction_include_action?(:create))", @callback_id=362>, #<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fce8a697ea8 @klass=User(id: integer, gender: string, name: string, email: string, fb_id: integer, fb_token: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, interested_in: text, last_login: datetime, access_token: string, access_token_expires: datetime, last_refreshed_friends_at: datetime, dob: date, fofs_available: boolean, updating_graph: boolean, last_daily_picks_seen_at: datetime, limitless_daily_picks: boolean, dps_limit: integer), @kind=:after, @chain=[...], @per_key={:if=>[], :unless=>[]}, @options={:on=>:create, :if=>["transaction_include_action?(:create)"], :unless=>[]}, @raw_filter=:send_welcome_email, @filter=:send_welcome_email, @compiled_options="true && (transaction_include_action?(:create))", @callback_id=366>, #<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fce8a696f58 ...>], @per_key={:if=>[], :unless=>[]}, @options={:on=>:create, :if=>["transaction_include_action?(:create)"], :unless=>[]}, @raw_filter=:create_settings, @filter=:create_settings, @compiled_options="true && (transaction_include_action?(:create))", @callback_id=370>, #<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fce8a6957e8 @klass=User(id: integer, gender: string, name: string, email: string, fb_id: integer, fb_token: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, interested_in: text, last_login: datetime, access_token: string, access_token_expires: datetime, last_refreshed_friends_at: datetime, dob: date, fofs_available: boolean, updating_graph: boolean, last_daily_picks_seen_at: datetime, limitless_daily_picks: boolean, dps_limit: integer), @kind=:after, @chain=[#<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fce8a691738 @klass=User(id: integer, gender: string, name: string, email: string, fb_id: integer, fb_token: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, interested_in: text, last_login: datetime, access_token: string, access_token_expires: datetime, last_refreshed_friends_at: datetime, dob: date, fofs_available: boolean, updating_graph: boolean, last_daily_picks_seen_at: datetime, limitless_daily_picks: boolean, dps_limit: integer), @kind=:after, @chain=[#<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fce8a691738 ...>], @per_key={:if=>[], :unless=>[]}, @options={:on=>:create, :if=>["transaction_include_action?(:create)"], :unless=>[]}, @raw_filter=:logging, @filter=:logging, @compiled_options="true && (transaction_include_action?(:create))", @callback_id=362>, #<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fce8a697ea8 @klass=User(id: integer, gender: string, name: string, email: string, fb_id: integer, fb_token: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, interested_in: text, last_login: datetime, access_token: string, access_token_expires: datetime, last_refreshed_friends_at: datetime, dob: date, fofs_available: boolean, updating_graph: boolean, last_daily_picks_seen_at: datetime, limitless_daily_picks: boolean, dps_limit: integer), @kind=:after, @chain=[#<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fce8a691738 @klass=User(id: integer, gender: string, name: string, email: string, fb_id: integer, fb_token: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, interested_in: text, last_login: datetime, access_token: string, access_token_expires: datetime, last_refreshed_friends_at: datetime, dob: date, fofs_available: boolean, updating_graph: boolean, last_daily_picks_seen_at: datetime, limitless_daily_picks: boolean, dps_limit: integer), @kind=:after, @chain=[#<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fce8a691738 ...>], @per_key={:if=>[], :unless=>[]}, @options={:on=>:create, :if=>["transaction_include_action?(:create)"], :unless=>[]}, @raw_filter=:logging, @filter=:logging, @compiled_options="true && (transaction_include_action?(:create))", @callback_id=362>, #<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fce8a697ea8 ...>, #<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fce8a696f58 @klass=User(id: integer, gender: string, name: string, email: string, fb_id: integer, fb_token: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, interested_in: text, last_login: datetime, access_token: string, access_token_expires: datetime, last_refreshed_friends_at: datetime, dob: date, fofs_available: boolean, updating_graph: boolean, last_daily_picks_seen_at: datetime, limitless_daily_picks: boolean, dps_limit: integer), @kind=:after, @chain=[...], @per_key={:if=>[], :unless=>[]}, @options={:on=>:create, :if=>["transaction_include_action?(:create)"], :unless=>[]}, @raw_filter=:create_settings, @filter=:create_settings, @compiled_options="true && (transaction_include_action?(:create))", @callback_id=370>], @per_key={:if=>[], :unless=>[]}, @options={:on=>:create, :if=>["transaction_include_action?(:create)"], :unless=>[]}, @raw_filter=:send_welcome_email, @filter=:send_welcome_email, @compiled_options="true && (transaction_include_action?(:create))", @callback_id=366>, #<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fce8a696f58 @klass=User(id: integer, gender: string, name: string, email: string, fb_id: integer, fb_token: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, interested_in: text, last_login: datetime, access_token: string, access_token_expires: datetime, last_refreshed_friends_at: datetime, dob: date, fofs_available: boolean, updating_graph: boolean, last_daily_picks_seen_at: datetime, limitless_daily_picks: boolean, dps_limit: integer), @kind=:after, @chain=[#<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fce8a691738 @klass=User(id: integer, gender: string, name: string, email: string, fb_id: integer, fb_token: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, interested_in: text, last_login: datetime, access_token: string, access_token_expires: datetime, last_refreshed_friends_at: datetime, dob: date, fofs_available: boolean, updating_graph: boolean, last_daily_picks_seen_at: datetime, limitless_daily_picks: boolean, dps_limit: integer), @kind=:after, @chain=[#<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fce8a691738 ...>], @per_key={:if=>[], :unless=>[]}, @options={:on=>:create, :if=>["transaction_include_action?(:create)"], :unless=>[]}, @raw_filter=:logging, @filter=:logging, @compiled_options="true && (transaction_include_action?(:create))", @callback_id=362>, #<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fce8a697ea8 @klass=User(id: integer, gender: string, name: string, email: string, fb_id: integer, fb_token: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, interested_in: text, last_login: datetime, access_token: string, access_token_expires: datetime, last_refreshed_friends_at: datetime, dob: date, fofs_available: boolean, updating_graph: boolean, last_daily_picks_seen_at: datetime, limitless_daily_picks: boolean, dps_limit: integer), @kind=:after, @chain=[...], @per_key={:if=>[], :unless=>[]}, @options={:on=>:create, :if=>["transaction_include_action?(:create)"], :unless=>[]}, @raw_filter=:send_welcome_email, @filter=:send_welcome_email, @compiled_options="true && (transaction_include_action?(:create))", @callback_id=366>, #<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback:0x007fce8a696f58 ...>], @per_key={:if=>[], :unless=>[]}, @options={:on=>:create, :if=>["transaction_include_action?(:create)"], :unless=>[]}, @raw_filter=:create_settings, @filter=:create_settings, @compiled_options="true && (transaction_include_action?(:create))", @callback_id=370>]
```

Here's the result of running them on the last User:

```
irb(main):002:0> User.last.run_callbacks :commit
  User Load (30.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> true
```

Comment: If you open a Rails console on Heroku, does `User._commit_callbacks` list the callbacks? Can you run them manually with `User.last.run_callbacks :commit`?

Comment: Please post logging methods

Comment: just added both to the question, thanks!

Comment: any ideas?  looks like the callbacks should be running, yet i don't see evidence of them (either with the logging method nor the send_welcome_email method).

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured this out:

1. Subsequent calls to after_commit were overwriting the ones before them.
2. Calls within after_commit silently fail.
3. The last call was failing (silently).

I've combined all of the methods into one after_commit call and fixed the failing call.